# How to log all requests with Playwright

Tags: typescript, automated-tests, playwright

I use playwright's request: APIRequestContext fixture to implement API tests, and I'd like to log all request/responses, but I cannot figure out how.
In case of Page fixture, I can monitor the network traffic and log them, but the Request fixture does not provide anything similar.

I use an extended playwright/test and override / add additional fixtures, based on: https://playwright.dev/docs/test-fixtures#overriding-fixtures

Any ideas for a top level solution to log all traffic made view Request fixture?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `request.on('response')` event to log the response:

```
const request = context.request({
  url: 'https://example.com',
  method: 'GET',
});

request.on('response', (response) =&gt; {
  console.log(response.status());
  console.log(response.headers());
  console.log(response.body());
});

await request.send();
```

Comment: .on('response) is not available for APIRequestContext